Deployment Issue on Render.com: "Exited with status 1 while building your code"
I'm trying to deploy a Java Spring backend application on Render.com, but I'm encountering an issue during the deployment process. Whenever I attempt to deploy, I receive the following error message: "Exited with status 1 while building your code."
Here's the Dockerfile I'm using for the deployment:

FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:17.0.1-jdk-slim
COPY --from=build /target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "demo.jar"]

I've ensured that the Maven build completes successfully on my local machine, and the generated JAR file (demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) exists in the /target directory.
Could anyone help me identify the cause of this issue? I'm relatively new to Docker and deployment processes, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
my github repo link => https://github.com/JadhavC07/Java-MySQL-Server

Your Dockerfile works for me. I have just tested it on Render and GitHub with my own project. Check the full log output and share it here, please.

From your code I can see you have a local database configured. To work with database on Render you need to purchase it (afaik) and start with Docker as well. Or you can switch to the embedded H2 for testing.

don't know where to locate logs of failure on render , do need purchase plan on render to deploy my back-end?

With a free plan you can have a Web Service and even a small PostgreSQL database. From the dashboard click on new Web Service from GitHub with Docker Runtime. When you get your Web Service you can click Deploy latest commit. The logs will show up. And they can be displayed using the navigation on the left.
